# 1503 A UNIQUE INDEX must include all columns in the table's partitioning function

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm trying to change column to unique but I'm getting this error.

What should I do for change my column ?

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: 
General error: 1503 A UNIQUE INDEX must include all columns in the
table's partitioning function (SQL: alter table `location` add unique 
`location_locationid_unique`(`locationID`))
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are using MYSQL ?

Comment: yes I'm sure what I'm using.

Comment: I think location table is partitioned, if so then you have to include those columns too in the `UNIQUE` key list.

Comment: I think the error message is pretty clear.  You have a partitioned table and the unique index doesn't match the partitioning keys.

Comment: Yes I partioned the location table I'm trying to that now.

Answer (score 2):

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; meanwhile,...

It is a restriction of `PARTITIONing` that you cannot have a `UNIQUEness` constraint that does not include the "partition key".

Please provide the rationale for partitioning at all.  *Most* uses of partitioning do not provide *any* benefit.  In fact, I believe there are [*only 4 use cases*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/partition-maintenance/#use-cases-for-partitioning) .

With the `CREATE TABLE`, we can discuss workarounds.